# I find myself with lots of money. What can I spend it on?

Tags: solatorobo-red-the-hunter

I keep getting money for completing missions. Loads of it. Problem is, the only thing I have found to spend it on is upgrades for my Dahak.

What's the problem with that, you may ask? I am lacking the slots to put the upgrades in, because finding the P Crystals I need to unlock slots is rather slow going.

Is there anything else I can spend my hard-earned riches on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Voyons...* Fishing!!!

Or save up for RARE parts. They get VERY expensive. They will appear in "New Game+" and "New Game++." Every time you beat the game you can start it over, more parts will appear. There will be a new NPC on the deck of the Duel Ship. There are 6 versions of each type of rare part. You will have access to the 5 and 6 versions in the second and third playthrough respectively.

You can also buy X versions of each Dahak type (R, G, C, and  S) after you beat the game the first time (gives you extra combo hits, +stats, alt colors, etc). The Omega type is unlocked on your third playthrough (buy it for a cool 60K Rings)...

Whatever leftover money you have left after all that, burn it on magic cinematic ceramic plates (can't explain THAT!).